# How do I use python and selenium to find the element of a radio button using the text related to the radio button?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to write a code that I can use to automate a training course that I have to do every year. It is the same material and the same training year after year, so I figured why not automate it.

The part that I  am stuck is clicking on a radio button. I am able to select the radio button through using find element by xpath, but because the answers are randomized I would like to find the element by the text related to the radio button. I have tried using `find_element_by_partial_link` and had no luck, I could also being doing it wrong. This is what I have tried:

```
test = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Is this achievable?').
```

Here is the element that I am trying to access:

```
<label for="q1789110:1_answer0" style="background-color: rgb(234, 114, 0);" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1509578998475_118">Is this achievable?</label>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: could you share the link of the webpage?

Comment: Give us entire HTML page.

Comment: I think the `id` for the `label` is dynamic which will change for each and every question. `Is this achievable?` will be a common text for all the `labels`. So in-order to find/locate/search the relative `Is this achievable?` label with respect to the exact question, you may require to share the `HTML` of the `Question` as well as of the `Labels`

Comment: Yes my apologize for sending the full URL. With sending the full URL it requires you to long it. Is this an issue? I am new to stackoverflow, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: https://fa.financialavenue.org/fa/mod/quiz/attempt.php?attempt=1789111

Comment: @JPython We should have an account in order to see that

Answer (score 0):

If this is your element:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello!")
}
</script>


<label for="q1789110:1_answer0" style="background-color: rgb(234, 114, 0);" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1509578998475_118" onclick="myFunction()">Is this achievable?</label>
```

and you want to use the xpath, you can use the and condition with `"text()"`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@id='yui_3_17_2_3_1509578998475_118' and text()='Is this achievable?']").click()
```

**EDIT**

If the id changes, you can just check the text value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Is this achievable?']").click()
```

Comment: I haven't tried anything including the "text()=" but my issue with using the Id is that every time the page loads that ID of the element changes and it causes issues.

Comment: @JPython ok, if the id changes you can just use the "text()" value to identify the element

Answer (score 0):

If your html code look like this

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can first use xpath in order to find label node using text and then get it's 'for' attribute:

```
for_attr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Male']").get_attribute("for")
```

Then you can find the input element in order to click on it:

By xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @id='%s']" % (for_attr)).click()
```

or by id

```
driver.find_element_by_id(for_attr).click()
```

[The for attribute of the label tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)